# Molly fish still has popeye after numerous water changes and medication

Tags: aquarium, fish, medicines

I have some black mollies that developed popeye. I noticed a subtle white area toward the back of their body (that doesn't look like fungus or ich), and there's possible inflammation of their gills. There doesn't appear to be "pineconing" (at least that I can see), so I don't think that they have dropsy.

I tried water changes and improving the water quality at first, then I tried Fin and Body Cure. Neither of these helped. I did 20% water changes on the 3rd and 5th day as instructed and put the filter back in to remove the remainder of the Fin and Body Cure.

I've been doing 20% water changes every few days. I've tested the water and they show no nitrates, nitrites, or ammonia (I did a fish-in cycle using Seachem Stability and periodically add more of that on water changes). PH is about 7.5. The water is quite hard, but I've been working on slowly decreasing it; the Calcium Hardness is around 180 and the general hardness is still showing at around 240 (which I'm at least slightly skeptical of). Water temperature is 75.6 and stable. Obviously, I treat the water to remove chlorine when I do water changes. The water is filtered. I try to match the water I'm adding to be close to the water temperature of the tank to avoid large temperature swings, and I typically use Seachem Stress Guard on the day of a water change (and typically for a day or two afterwards) in case there was any unintentional injury to fish in the process.

After that, I tried food medicated with Kanaplex and Seachem Focus (using the formula recommended by the manufacturer). That made no difference either.

I'm now trying E.M. Erythromycin, Melafix, and Pimafix; however, I'm on the fourth day of the treatment (which is the last day of the antibiotic) and my fish don't look any different.

I feed them diverse food, including Aqueon Color Enhancing Tropical Flakes, Omega One Freshwater Flakes, and periodically daphnia (to help prevent constipation).

Right now, I have 3 adult and 4 juvenile mollies plus a few aquatic snails in a 29-gallon tank.

I plan to continue for the full 7-day course of Melafix and Pimafix, but given the lack of any noticeable progress so far, I don't have much confidence. (For the record, I am aware that there's controversy about how effective those treatments are).

I've read that aquarium salt can help, but I'm somewhat afraid to try it due to the aquatic snails. However, I could probably move them to a different tank if I had to. I'm a little worried about doing that, though, because my other tank already has fish in it, and I want to avoid spreading any kind of disease between my two tanks.

Pictures (sorry about the so-so quality, it's the best I could get):
[image]

[image]

Is there something else I can try?

Comment: @Guest never ever use rock salt in any fishtank,the salt to use in a fishtank is aquarium salt(pure seasalt with different mineral salts added).